# Using string interpolation, how to pad with a given character?

Tags: c#, c#-6.0

I know I'm in danger here, but couldn't find in SO/Google:

Using string interpolation, how do I pad with a given character? for instance:

```
foreach (var p in people) {
    Console.WriteLine($"{p.Name,-10}: {p.Age}");
}
```

Will result in (e.g.):

```
Joe       : 26
Dan       : 52
```

How do I change the spaces with dots, **via string interpolation**? to get:

```
Joe.......: 26
Dan.......: 52
```

(I know I can do `p.Name.PadRight(10,'.')`, but I'm pretty sure there's a way with string-interpolation parameters, like the padding length).

Comment: In the current version of C#, this does not work `{p.Name:10}`. The correct format for left-aligned, padded with 10 spaces is to use a comma and negative value for left-alignment like this `{p.Name,-10}`. A positive value performs right-alignment.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated#structure-of-an-interpolated-string

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Browsing through [Microsoft's Docs for the alignment component](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/composite-formatting#alignment-component) for string formatting, I found this little excerpt.

> If padding is necessary, white space is used.

You're stuck with whitespace if you're going to use string interpolation. As you noted earlier, `string.PadRight()` will suffice as a workaround.

Comment: @Tar did you try out the solution I posted below? Or its not what you were looking for.

Comment: @RazvanR, I was aware of that option, I was hoping for a cleaner solution via the string-interpolation mechanism

Comment: Oh ok got it @Tar

Answer (score 4):

@Tar why dont you try this:

```
var paddingWithChar = new string ('.', lengthOfPaddingAsInt); 

Console.WriteLine ($"{p.Name}{paddingWithChar}:{p.Age,10}");
```

Comment: this won't do... https://repl.it/@genuinefafa/Padding-with-String-Interpolation-C

Comment: That does not answer the question of how to select the padding character using string interpolation. Also, it pads the age which was not part of the problem.